# Make that one rest api does not need any logging

Tags: regex, rest, spring-mvc, url, spring-security

There is a Spring Security configuration in my application, so all the rest interfaces need to pass some filters and authentication.

This is the security configuration I have:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class MyProgramSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    ....
    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.addFilterBefore(restBasedAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint())
        .and()
        .logout().permitAll(false)
        .addLogoutHandler(logoutHandler).logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher(LOGIN_PATH, HttpMethod.DELETE.toString()))
        .logoutSuccessHandler(getLogoutSuccessHandler())
        .and()
        .sessionManagement().maximumSessions(5);

        http.addFilterAfter(termsAndConditionsFilter, TermAndConditionFilter.class);
        http.addFilterAfter(certificateValidationFilter, TermsAndConditionsFilter.class);
        ... // some other filters
    }
    ....
}
```

But, as I described in the title of the question, I would like to have one endpoint `/internal/application/info` that can be called by anyone without any need of authentication, logging or whatever. I think that you can do it with `regexMatcher`, am I right?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should to add one more method of HttpSecurity class, something like that:

```
....
.and()
.authorizeRequests()
.antMatchers("/internal/application/info")
.permitAll()
....
```